# github project clone in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new in Flutter and github and want to clone a flutter project from github but can't do that probably because of this error

```
''Packages get' has not been run'
```

[image]

Whenever I press 'Get dependencies' nothing happen, the message stay.

Comment: did you run the command `flutter packages get` ?

Comment: if the command that @AhmedKhattab suggested doesn't work, please update the question with the result of the command `flutter doctor -v` and also the GitHub URL of the project you are cloning. This way we can help you more.

Comment: running flutter doctor -v the result is no issues found.
should I run flutter packages get in flutter console or android studio terminal ?
in flutter console the error is "Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter."
https://github.com/devefy/Flutter-Story-App-UI the link of github project

Comment: @Develloper4587 in the android terminal, a path relative to the root of your project

Comment: now your good to go, flutter run should work